# Using a Prolog rule to display the first element of a given list, within a query?

Tags: prolog

this is the second part of a question on a paradigms exam paper that I'm currently working my way through and it's got me a bit stumped, but then I'm still quite a prolog noob so the solution is probably obvious..

I wrote this rule/fact `contains1(X, [X|_]).` for checking if the given element is equal to the head of the given list.
This is fine, it works as expected and from all my reading I'm maybe 95% sure that's the best way to go about it. But then the question also says to write a prolog query *using this rule* to display the first element in a given list.

I'm using swi-prolog to enter and test all my rules etc and the only way I know how to get it to display the first element of a given list is with the query `[H|T] = (some_list)`. So how exactly do I work my rule into this..? Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make prolog find out what value of X makes the clause valid:

```
contains(X, sample_list).
```

For example,

```
contains(X, [1, 2, 3]).
```

will return `X = 1`, because when `X = 1`, then the clause is true.

Remember that, when given a clause like this, Prolog will try to look for all values of X such that that clause becomes true.

Comment: Ah of course! I've even entered queries like this before, it must just be my brain at this time of morning, thank you :)